# CherryPy: Perform specific action if user goes to specific URL

Tags: python, cherrypy

I'm new to CherryPy so please bear with me. What I'd like to do is perform a specific action when a user goes to a specific URL. The URL will mostly always be the same except for one part. The URL will be something like: http://myserver.mydomain.com/show_item.cgi?id=12345. The URL will always be the same except for the 12345. I want to take the "string of numbers", plop them into a variable, and re-direct to another URL that will be built on the fly based on that variable. I have the logic for building out the URL -- I just don't know how to "intercept" the incoming URL and extract the "string of numbers". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are new to CherryPy you should try to [read the docs](http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/) before asking a question like this and show us what you have already tried to solve your problem. At least very few pages of documenation, which actually [answer your question](http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials.html#tutorial-3-my-urls-have-parameters).

Comment: Doh! I actually did read a bunch of these docs...I don't know how I missed it. The only issue with this is that it means my function name has to have a '.' in it (show_item.cgi) which of course Python doesn't like. Any ideas on how to get around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, it was not clear from your question that you really wanted to mock CGI-like file handler URL. Though the answer [is still there](http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/3.3.0/tutorial/dispatching.html#special-characters), it may be harder to find because of recent changes in documentation.

> You can use dots in a URI like `/path/to/my.html`, but Python method names don’t 
>   allow dots. To work around this, the default dispatcher converts all dots in the 
>   URI to underscores before trying to find the page handler. In the example, 
>   therefore, you would name your page handler `def my_html`.

So with the following you can navigate your browser to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/show_item.cgi?id=1234`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import cherrypy


config = {
  'global' : {
    'server.socket_host' : '127.0.0.1',
    'server.socket_port' : 8080,
    'server.thread_pool' : 8
  }
}


class App:

  @cherrypy.expose
  def show_item_cgi(self, id):
    raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect('https://google.com/search?q={0:d}'.format(int(id)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  cherrypy.quickstart(App(), '/', config)
```

Answer (score 0):

saaj I think really did answer my question by pointing me [here](http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials.html#tutorial-3-my-urls-have-parameters). My follow-up is unique to my scenario so I'll research that more and ask a different question if I need to.